# Writing Unit tests for a private function.. Unsure of proper strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, shoulda

My code.. :

```
after_save :handle_test

private

def handle_test
  if parent.try(:is_test)
    Resque.enqueue UnpackTestOnS3, parent.id
  end
end
```

I'm trying to strategize the best way to test this Model logic.

Do I test that Resque received something?
Do I test that `parent.try(:is_test)` is true? If so, it would be kind of silly because in the test itself I would have to stub that or update_attribute..
Is this too granular to test at all?
Should I, instead just be testing that a file appears on S3? I'm not sure that would make sense for a unit test to actually upload something to S3.

All strategies warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test the fact that there is a job queued for unpacking when you create or update your model

```
it "should enqueue job to unpack test on s3 on creating <model_name>" do
  Resque.should_receive(:enqueue).with(UnpackTestOnS3, <parent_id>)
end

it "should enqueue job to unpack test on s3 on updating <model_name>" do
  Resque.should_receive(:enqueue).with(UnpackTestOnS3, <parent_id>)
end

it "should not enqueue job to unpack test on s3 when the <model_name>'s parent is not for test" do
  Resque.should_not_receive(:enqueue).with(UnpackTestOnS3, <parent_id>)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vimsha, I really sincerely appreciate it.